# What is .sql file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have heard about .sql file in SQL Server, But i don't know what it holds also is this file helpful for recovery purpose?

Comment: So, what have you heard about the .sql file?

Comment: I have heard that SQL Server uses .sql file, but i don't know for what purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.sql file is the script file of sql server that contain the all command of particular database...

**Including**

**- Create
 - Select
 - Insert
 - Store Processor
 - View**

Comment: Thanks for the help but i also want to know that the .sql file can also be used for recovery purpose?

Comment: @JasonClark Yes, If you lost your database then you can execute .sql file. .sql file is one type of a backup file.

Answer (score 1):

SQL, or Structured Query Language files contain SQL code used to modify the contents of a database. They may contain statements for creating or modifying database structures, insertions or updates, deletions.

Your result will be based on what your code in .SQL says.